# If $X$ follows a $\chi^{2}_{k}$, what is the distribution of $-X$?

Tags: gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I know that if If $X$ follows a $\chi^{2}_{k}$, then $cX$ $(c>0)$ follows a $\Gamma(k/2,2c)$, what about when $c<0$?

Comment: How should one answer your question?  To most people, to say that $-X$ is a chi-squared distribution would be a full, accurate, and very helpful answer.  What are you looking for?  Surely not the PDF or the CDF, which are trivial transformations of the chi-squared versions, so what, then?

Comment: I think the distribution would be the mirror image of the gamma distribution for c > 0.  This is not a chi square distribution.

Comment: @whuber Are you saying -X is chi-squared?

Comment: @whuber, I don't think it's a chi-squared distribution, because  the values of $-X$ are less than or equal $0$, plus simulations suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

So $X \sim \chi^2_k$ and $c<0$. Following your post, then $\vert c \vert X \sim \Gamma(k/2, 2\vert c \vert)$ so $c X= -\vert c \vert X $ has the distribution of a gamma distributed random variable multiplied by $-1$, that is, reflected in the vertical axis.  We could also call that a *scaled chisquare distribution*, there is no reason to avoid that term just because the scaling factor is negative.